# CakePHP looping over two find arrays

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

So I'm just trying to loop over two arrays the I queried for.

```
         $draftedPlayers = $this->DraftedPlayer->find ( 'all', array (
            'conditions' => array (
                    'leagueId' => $draft ['Draft'] ['id'] 
                     ) 
             ));
```

And

```
         $players = $this->Player->find('all');
```

I just want to remove all results of `$draftedPlayers` from `$players`  where `$draftedPlayers['DraftedPlayer']['playerId']` is equal to `$players['Player']['id']` Does cakePHP have a build in helper for this? I'm not really sure how to compare these two objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `foreach` loop will achieve what you want to do:

```
foreach($players as &$player) { // loop the players (with referenced iterator)
    foreach($draftedPlayers as $drafted_player) { // inner loop, drafted playerd
        if($player['Player']['id'] == $drafted_player['DraftedPlayer']['playerId']) {
            unset($player); // compare the keys and remove where matching
            break; // skip the rest of the inner loop
        }
    }
}
```

However depending on how many entries in each array you have this might be 1000 reps with an inner loop of 1000 reps (1,000,000 if statements).

A better way to compare would be to **join** the DraftedPlayer to the Player and put a condition in that it doesn't find a match, something like:

```
$players = $this->Player->find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'drafted_players',
            'alias' => 'DraftedPlayer',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'DraftedPlayer.playerId = Player.id',
                'DraftedPlayer.leagueId' => $draft['Draft']['id']
            )
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        // your general conditions here
        'DraftedPlayer.playerId IS NULL' // only return un matched results from players table
        // which essentially means the player is NOT drafted
    )
));
```

Haven't tested this code, but that's the general idea... Of course, it would be better to do this through [CakePHP's model associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) rather than a manual join like above.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea about the Associations, I'll try to go that route.